# Sort all arrays in object using javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, typescript

I want to sort every array in this object, currently i do it this way

```
this.userInfo = {
    Interests: [],
    Websites: [],
    Games: [],
    Locations: [],
    Companies: [],
    Projects: [],
    Schools: [],
    Studies: []
};


this.userInfo.Interests.sort();
this.userInfo.Websites.sort();
this.userInfo.Games.sort();
this.userInfo.Locations.sort();
this.userInfo.Companies.sort();
this.userInfo.Projects.sort();
this.userInfo.Schools.sort();
this.userInfo.Studies.sort();
```

Any other more elegant way?

Comment: do a for(var prop in this.userInfo) this.userInfo[prop].sort();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all array's own property names, then iterate the keys using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
Object.keys(this.userInfo).forEach(function(key) {
  this.userInfo[key].sort(function(a, b) {
    // your sorting logic
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this this will help you,

```js
this.userInfo = {
  Interests: [2, 3, 4, 1],
  Websites: [2, 3, 4, 1],
  Games: [2, 3, 4, 1],
  Locations: [2, 3, 4, 1],
  Companies: [2, 3, 4, 1],
  Projects: [2, 3, 4, 1],
  Schools: [2, 3, 4, 1],
  Studies: [2, 3, 4, 1]
};

for (var i in this.userInfo) {
  console.log(this.userInfo[i].sort());
}
```